# How to mimic computeHash vb function in PHP

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption, md5

I am having a hell of a time trying to md5 hash this with PHP... The VB code I am trying to port to PHP uses ComputeHash which takes in a byte[]  and performs a hash on the whole array.

```
    Public Shared Function HashBytesMD5(ByVal strInput As String) As Guid
        Dim oHasher As Cryptography.MD5 = Cryptography.MD5.Create()
        Dim oEncoder As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
        Dim csData() As Byte

    csData = oEncoder.GetBytes(strInput)
    csData = oHasher.ComputeHash(oEncoder.GetBytes(strInput))
        Return New Guid(csData)
    End Function
```

Right now I have the following which creates an array of ascii values. Now I need to md5 it like VB.Net does. It doesn't seem to be as straightforward as it may seem.

```
  $passHash = $this->ConvertToASCII('123456');
  $passHash = md5(serialize($passHash));


     /*
     * Converts a string to ascii (byte) array
     */
    function ConvertToASCII($password)
    {
        $byteArray = array();

        for ($i=0; $i < strlen($password); $i++)  {
            array_push($byteArray,ord(substr($password,$i)));
        }

        return $byteArray;
    }
```

Note: the values in the first are the acii values for the characters 123456

Byte array before computeHash md5

```
  **index**     **Value**                  
      [0]          49                           
      [1]          50            
      [2]          51               
      [3]          52                  
      [4]          53                 
      [5]          54
```

Byte array returned from VB computeHash function
**index**    **value**

```
[0]           225                                     
[1]           10                    
[2]           220                
[3]           57                           
[4]           73                          
[5]           186                     
[6]           89      
[7]           171
[8]           190
[9]           86
[10]          224
[11]          87
[12]          242
[13]          15
[14]          136
[15]          62
```

Comment: On first look I'm not sure this would be done by md5'ing a serialized array of bytes. Sidenote: the way you're using `substr()` takes all the string starting at `$i`, whereas I think you just want that single character: `substr($password, $i, 1)`

Comment: I got the php function from a comment in the php manual. I did a print_r and it seems to work.

Comment: nvm you were right :) Nice catch.

Comment: Yup it just works because `ord()` only cares about the first given character :) I think I got it, posting answer because there's code in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My VB.NET is very rusty but it seems like `MD5.ComputeHash()`'s output could be recreated by running your input through `md5()` and then taking each pair of hex characters (byte) and converting into decimal.

```
$passHash = md5('123456');
$strlen = strlen($passHash) ;

$hashedBytes = array() ;
$i = 0 ;
while ($i < $strlen) {
    $pair = substr($passHash, $i, 2) ;
    $hashedBytes[] = hexdec($pair) ;
    $i = $i + 2 ;
}
```

Comment: wow, nice work! I don't think I would have got that anytime soon :) By any chance would you know how to convert that to a .net style GUID?

Answer (score 4):

By the power of magic, the following will work:

```
function get_VB_hash($text)
{
    $hash = md5($text);
    $hex = pack('H*', $hash);  // Pack as a hex string
    $int_arr = unpack('C*', $hex);  // Unpack as unsigned chars

    return $int_arr;
}
```

or as one line:

`unpack('C*', pack('H*', md5($text)) );`

Proof:

```
C:\>php -r "print_r( unpack('C*', pack('H*', md5('123456') )) );"
Array
(
    [1] => 225
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 220
    [4] => 57
    [5] => 73
    [6] => 186
    [7] => 89
    [8] => 171
    [9] => 190
    [10] => 86
    [11] => 224
    [12] => 87
    [13] => 242
    [14] => 15
    [15] => 136
    [16] => 62
)
```

Comment: Better, performance wise. Use this and avoid the loops I did that only show what ComputeHash() does.