# MD5 Hashing between VB.net and PHP

Tags: php, .net, md5

**Answered with the help of @JonSkeet**

Given this code:

```
    Dim data1ToHash As Byte() = (New UnicodeEncoding).GetBytes(input)
    ' 2. Hash the byte array
    Dim hashvalue1 As Byte() = CType(CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("MD5"), HashAlgorithm).ComputeHash(data1ToHash)
```

Shouldn't this PHP produce the correct hash?

`$md5 = (md5(utf8_encode($signature), true));`

I tried, but the md5sums aren't matching up. I assumed it was encoding, but perhaps it has to do with the byte array, can anyone shed some light on this? FYI I can't change the VB

To compare the results:

in .Net

```
For Each b As Byte In hashvalue1
  tb.Text = tb.Text & b.ToString() & ","
Next
tb.Text = tb.Text.Trim(",")
```

in PHP

`print_r(unpack('C*', pack('H*', md5($signature))))`

as per another question

Comment: Confirm that the data you are hashing is identical.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mimic computeHash vb function in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544884/how-to-mimic-computehash-vb-function-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution had to do with byte ordering: .NET in UTF-16 was Little Endian, whereas PHP's default UTF-16 encoding is Big Endian. So the answer is:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$string = mb_convert_encoding($signature, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
$encoded_signature = base64_encode(md5($string, true));
```

To verify, I compared the UTF-16 encoded bytes in PHP and .NET:

```
print_r(unpack('C*', $string));
```

Just that simple. Thanks to everyone who helped, especially @JonSkeet.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear how you're comparing the results, but the encoding is *definitely a problem - you're using UTF-16 in the VB code, and UTF-8 in the PHP. You can change the VB code like this:

```
Dim data1ToHash As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)
```

The MD5 part can also be simplified, giving this result:

```
Dim unhashed As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)
Dim hashed As Byte() = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(unhashed)
```

EDIT: If you can't change the VB, you need to change the PHP to use UTF-16, potentially with [mbstring](https://www.php.net/mbstring) as suggested in comments. You'll need to know what the existing encoding is, of course...

Comment: Good point, I'll update the post, but I'm afraid I can't change the VB.

Comment: @scottkf You could probably use [mbstring](http://www.php.net/mbstring) from your PHP to convert from UTF8 to UTF16.

Comment: @jon-skeet then shouldn't the following produce correct results?        `$string = mb_convert_encoding(utf8_encode($signature), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');`
`$md5 = (md5($string, true));`

Comment: @scottkf: No, because you're then still encoding the UTF-16 version as UTF-8 (in a way which is broken, actually, as the input to utf8_encode expects iso-8859-1) before passing it to md5. Without the final utf8_encode that *might* be okay. But I don't know enough about PHP's string representation to know for sure.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The problem was in the representation of the bytes. VB.net was using LE for UTF-16, whereas PHP's UTF-16 is actually big endian. The solution is: `$string = mb_convert_encoding($signature, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'); $encoded_signature = base64_encode(md5($string, true));` It was verified by doing: `$raw = unpack('C*', $string); print_r($raw);`

Comment: @scottkf: That's converting *from* UTF-16 rather than *to* UTF-16 though isn't it? I can see why the endianness would be a problem, but that solution doesn't look *quite* right. Glad it works now though - you should check it works for non-ASCII strings, mind you.